# How can I implement a hook system in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I want to implement a hook system in my Ruby code. For example, when a user connects to a socket, a hook `user_connected` should be triggered.

Throughout my code, other parts could then listen to and hook into this event, and when it is called, run their own code.

How can I implement something like this?

Comment: You will have more success with a better question.  Please add an example of a hook system you used in another language, or, something you've at least tried.  Start here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/observer/rdoc/Observable.html

Comment: Are you trying to implement such hook infrastructure from scratch (That'd be rather ambitious for someone just learning a programming language!), or are you merely looking for means (e.g. a library) that would provide you with such an infrastructure so that your program may use it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's *really* difficult for us to answer your question. We have no idea what your level of expertise is, nor have we an idea of what you've read or tried, what level of success you've had with that attempt, and trying to write answers that fill in all the blanks would take a book, making it off-topic. SO is about detailed answers to specific problems. You can help us help you by telling us a lot more and showing what you tried and explaining why it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

What you describe is the observer pattern. Ruby ships with the [Observable module](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Observable.html).